# How to group items from GridView into one item (this in QML)? Like iPhone does

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

I need to create an application in QML using GridView with some items, and I need to group them like in this iPhone [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-r7K4LTbI4A)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there have an _IphoneView_ in QML. Qt sample may help you http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another type of item - a `GridItem` item, in which you have another `GridView`.

Then it is a simple matter of taking a model item from the outer grid model and inserting it into the model of the grid item.

You can do the opposite to move an item back to the outer / main grid.

Of course, this means that the view delegate has to instantiate a different object type depending if a particular item is an icon or a group. You can do this via a `Loader` element with a conditional statement for the source property.